# Ayuda con inserción en base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, sql, bucle-for, jtable

Estoy trabajando con con java y `mysql`. Creé un `jframe` donde hay un pequeño formulario y después un `Jtable`, al llenar los datos del formulario y después darle a un botón para generar, el registro de ese formulario pasa al `Jtable`. Eso lo puedo hacer cuantas veces desee, pero la cuestión están en un botón para guardar los registros de ese `Jtable` en mi bdd. El botón de guardar recibe por medio de un **`for`** los registros de las filas del `Jtable` sin importar la cantidad de filas. Lo que pasa es que no me sale ningún error después de darle *guardar*, pero al revisar la tabla no me guarda nada. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Ya anexo el código

```
Connection accesoDB;
    conexion  conexion = new conexion();
    accesoDB  = conexion.getConnection();
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String sqlContenido = "INSERT INTO historialPresupuesto (id_trabajo, banco, tipoMantenimiento, herramienta, fecha, monto) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String fecha = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(""+fecha);
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i<tabledetalles.getRowCount(); i++){

            PreparedStatement ps;
            ps = accesoDB.prepareStatement(sqlContenido);
            ps.setNull(1, 0);
            ps.setString(2, (String) tabledetalles.getValueAt(i, 0)); //Banco
            ps.setString(3, (String) tabledetalles.getValueAt(i, 1)); //Tipo
            ps.setString(4, (String) tabledetalles.getValueAt(i, 2)); //Herramienta
            ps.setDate(5, Date.valueOf(fecha));
            ps.setString(6, (String) String.valueOf(tabledetalles.getValueAt(i, 3)));   //Monto
            //Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tabledetalles.getValueAt(i, 3)))
            System.out.println("Guardado");
        }
        accesoDB.close();

    }
    catch (SQLException ex ) {
        Logger.getLogger(calculo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"...Ocurrio un  error inesperado"+ ex);
    }
    LimpiarTodo();
}
```

El código del `Jtable` es el siguiente:

```
 private void btngenerarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


    //Valida que no hay campos vacíos
    if("Seleccione".equals(tipoMantenimiento_cbo.getSelectedItem().toString())){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Seleccione un tipo de mantenimiento", "Advertencia!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        tipoMantenimiento_cbo.requestFocus();

        if("Seleccion".equals(herramienta_cbo.getSelectedItem().toString())){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Seleccione un tipo de herramienta", "Advertencia!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        tipoMantenimiento_cbo.requestFocus();
    }
    }
    else if("Seleccione".equals(banco_cbo.getSelectedItem().toString())){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Seleccione el banco", "Advertencia!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        banco_cbo.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(monto_txt.getText().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ingrese el nombre monto", "Advertencia!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        monto_txt.requestFocus();
    }
    else{
        JButton botonEliminar   = new JButton();
        botonEliminar.setName("Elim");
        botonEliminar.setToolTipText("Botón de Eliminar en la linea seleccionada");
        botonEliminar.setEnabled(true);
        botonEliminar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/fs/investments/imagenes/eliminarP.png")));

        Object [] registros = new Object[5];        
        this.tabledetalles.setModel(modelo);
        //acepto renderizar la tabla para que acepte botones y otras atributos        
        this.tabledetalles.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new RenderJtable());
        //Condición para el banco
        //Si la opción es "Banesco" o "Plaza"
        if("Otro".equals(banco_cbo.getSelectedItem().toString())){
            registros[0] = nombreBanco_txt.getText();
        }
        //Si la selección es "Otro"
        else{
            registros[0] = banco_cbo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
        registros[1] = tipoMantenimiento_cbo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if("Preventivo".equals(tipoMantenimiento_cbo.getSelectedItem().toString())){
            registros[2] = "-----";
        }
        else{

            registros[2] = herramienta_cbo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
        registros[3] = Double.parseDouble(this.monto_txt.getText());
        registros[4] = botonEliminar;

         modelo.addRow(registros);
         LimpiarRegistro();
         SumarMontos();
         prepararPropiedad();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te está faltando ejecutar la PreparedStatement. Prueba con el siguiente codigo:

```
Connection accesoDB;
conexion  conexion = new conexion();
accesoDB  = conexion.getConnection();
ResultSet rs = null;

String sqlContenido = "INSERT INTO historialPresupuesto (id_trabajo, banco, 
tipoMantenimiento, herramienta, fecha, monto) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String fecha = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(""+fecha);
try {

    for (int i = 0; i<tabledetalles.getRowCount(); i++){

        PreparedStatement ps;
        ps = accesoDB.prepareStatement(sqlContenido);
        ps.setNull(1, 0);
        ps.setString(2, (String) tabledetalles.getValueAt(i, 0)); //Banco
        ps.setString(3, (String) tabledetalles.getValueAt(i, 1)); //Tipo
        ps.setString(4, (String) tabledetalles.getValueAt(i, 2)); //Herramienta
        ps.setDate(5, Date.valueOf(fecha));
        ps.setString(6, (String) String.valueOf(tabledetalles.getValueAt(i, 3)));   //Monto
        //Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tabledetalles.getValueAt(i, 3)))
        int row = ps.executeUpdate();             // <------------- ACA
        System.out.println("Se guardo " + row + " registro");
    }
    accesoDB.close();

}
catch (SQLException ex ) {
    Logger.getLogger(calculo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"...Ocurrio un  error inesperado"+ ex);
}
LimpiarTodo();
}
```

Espero que te sirva